# Signalr service side calls service point method with return value

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I defined a method on the client with a return value, and I want to return the return value to the service side while the service side calls. Could this demand be achieved

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so we have an idea of what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: You can not return values from client to server but the opposite direction is possible. You can return a value from server to client. If you want to pass a value to server, call another method of server.